# Multiple events handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

I have different files with javascript code that load different parts of my page. From different parts, I call ajax queries to get content. Once these ajax queries are done, I trigger my events:

```
//first.js
function initFormDetails(){
$.ajax({
  /*some code*/
  success:function(data){
     $(window).trigger('form-details-loaded');
  }
});
}

//second.js
function initFormInfo(){
$.ajax({
  /*some code*/
  success:function(data){
     $(window).trigger('form-info-loaded');
  }
});
}

//third.js
function initForm()
{
/*when form-details-loaded AND form-info-loaded: do some magic*/
}
```

I need to call some code once both events are triggered. What's the best way to do this? I've read a lot about deferred objects, but once these objects are resolved, there is no way to clear their state. It causes some problems for me because I have a lot of ajax calls in my project. Maybe jQuery has something else built-in to catch multiple events triggered?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all should get you started

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/